# Compare date, and place data under date

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have three sheets in one workbook. Two sheets contain data the user enters (SheetMain and SheetC1, names are fixed). This data has to be transferred to a third "history" or "log" sheet (SheetDest). The log has to be done this way, no external text file etc.

```
Sub Historie_speichern()

Dim SheetMain As Worksheet, SheetDest As Worksheet, SheetC1 As Worksheet
'Source and destination, as well as C1, another data entry sheet


Set SheetMain = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B1 PV Application") 'Main data entry sheet
Set SheetDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C0 EV (Historie)") 'Sheet for saving the history
Set SheetC1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C1 EV Application") 'another data entry sheet, usually done once

    
  
    SheetC1.Range("C4:F22").Copy
    SheetDest.Range("B2:E20").PasteSpecial xlValues 'Table C0 Part 1
    
    SheetC1.Range("N4:O22").Copy
    SheetDest.Range("F2:G20").PasteSpecial xlValues 'Table C0 Part 2.1
    
    SheetC1.Range("Q4:R22").Copy
    SheetDest.Range("H2:I20").PasteSpecial xlValues 'Table C0 Part 2.2
    
    SheetC1.Range("T4:U22").Copy
    SheetDest.Range("J2:K20").PasteSpecial xlValues 'Table C0 Part 2.3
    
    SheetC1.Range("W4:X22").Copy
    SheetDest.Range("L2:M20").PasteSpecial xlValues 'Table C0 Part 2.4
    
    SheetC1.Range("Z4:AA22").Copy
    SheetDest.Range("N2:O20").PasteSpecial xlValues 'Table C0 Part 2.5
```

This part works. Maybe someome has an idea for a loop, it just can't get it to work.

```
'loop through columns
Dim i As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim DataDate As Date


DataDate = SheetC1.Range("C2").value

' SheetDest.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 
For i = 21 To 100 'from column "S" to 100 (fixed range, 100/12months=8.3 years)

    If SheetDest.Cells(2, i).value = DataDate Then
        
        Cells(3, i).value = SheetC1.Range("AD27").value
        'in Range("AD27") is a KPI value calculated from the data table for one month
        'several of these values over time give a special curve that is used to assess performance
    Else
Exit For

    End If
    
Next i
 

End Sub
```

The log serves two purposes: Save the entered data for each month, and save a number calculated from the entered data and place it in the timeline under the respective month. The first part I will ask in another question.

"Datadate" (formatted as "general") compares its value to a fixed timeline next to the table (months from Jan.2024 to Jan.2030 displayed horizontally). My idea is that I loop through the columns/timeline, and when the dates match, the value is written under the date. The value of the timeline, e.g. "Jan.2023" is a vlookup.

How to make the second part work?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but there are easier ways to copy data inside an Excel workbook without passing by the clipboard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251.

Comment: I have read all of this stuff but I am not capable to apply it, yet, this is exactly why I' m asking here. IT is a lot of random and unsorted information touching various corners of the question.

My issue is that the data I am transfering is made of vlookup referneces, where I run into issues all the time. This way values are copied properly.

Answer (score 0):

- Please verify the data type of SheetC1.Range("C2") and SheetDest.Cells(2, i). It is essential to determine how to compare their values accurately.
- Please provide specific details if your file does not align with the assumptions made in the code. This will help in making any necessary adjustments or clarifications.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    'loop through columns
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim DataDate As String ' **
    Set SheetC1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C1 EV Application") ' Modify as needed
    Set SheetDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("C0 EV (Historie)")
    ' If C2 is formatted as "general" and shows `Jan.2024`
    ' It means C2 is a String instead of Date
    DataDate = SheetC1.Range("C2").Value
    For i = 21 To 100 'from column "S" to 100 (fixed range, 100/12months=8.3 years)
        ' Assumes SheetDest.Cells(2, i) is formatted as Date
        With SheetDest.Cells(2, i)
            If IsDate(.Value) Then
                If StrComp(Format(.Value, "MMM.yyyy"), DataDate, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                    Cells(3, i).Value = SheetC1.Range("AD27").Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: SheetC1.Range("C2")  is a dropdownlist placed via data -> data tools -> data validation, format is custom (MMM.YYYY). 
SheetDest.Cells(2, i) is the exact same format but referenced via a vlookup from another sheet, since the timeline can be changed by the user (he inputs a date range he wants to lok at, then within this date range he does everything else - project management)

Answer (score 0):

### A VBA Lookup: 'Application.Match' Date Using `CLng`

[image]

```vb
Sub Historie_speichern()

    Const SRC_NAME As String = "C1 EV Application"
    Const SRC_DATE_CELL As String = "C2"
    Const SRC_KPI_CELL As String = "AD27"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "C0 EV (Historie)"
    Const DST_DATES_LEFT_CELL As String = "S2"
    Const DST_KPI_ROW As Long = 3

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    Dim sDate As Date: sDate = sws.Range(SRC_DATE_CELL).Value
    Dim sKPI As Variant: sKPI = sws.Range(SRC_KPI_CELL).Value
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)

    With dws
        .Range("B2:E20").Value = sws.Range("C4:F22").Value
        .Range("F2:G20").Value = sws.Range("N4:O22").Value
        .Range("H2:I20").Value = sws.Range("Q4:R22").Value
        .Range("J2:K20").Value = sws.Range("T4:U22").Value
        .Range("L2:M20").Value = sws.Range("W4:X22").Value
        .Range("N2:O20").Value = sws.Range("Z4:AA22").Value
    End With
    
    Dim drrg As Range
    
    With dws.Range(DST_DATES_LEFT_CELL)
        Dim LastCol As Long:
        LastCol = dws.Cells(.Row, dws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set drrg = .Resize(, LastCol - .Column + 1)
    End With
        
    Dim cIndex As Variant: cIndex = Application.Match(CLng(sDate), drrg, 0)
        
    If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
        drrg.Cells(cIndex).EntireColumn.Cells(DST_KPI_ROW).Value = sKPI
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim sKPI As Variant`

Why do you use "variant" here and not "date"?

Comment: And what's this: 
`Dim LastCol As Long:
LastCol = dws.Cells(.Row, dws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` - 
declaration and code in one line?

Comment: And why do you use "Set" here? `Set drrg = .Resize(, LastCol - .Column + 1)`

Comment: 1.) It is irrelevant what `sKPI` is since it is only written to a cell. If it accidentally is not a date, why should the code fail? 2.) Variable declaration and assignment of a value to the variable in a single line. IMO, totally acceptable. 3.) `drrg` is a range: you gotta `set` (reference) a range (or any other object, e.g. workbook, worksheet....)!? It's a single row from `S2` to the right-most non-empty cell in row 2.